# How to save value from multiple requests to one file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have one GET request which returns a token. I need to run this request 50 times and each returned token is appended to a single file or array which I can randomly choose and use tokens for other requests. Is it possible in Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract the token and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Declare the variable as a [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
3. Save the extracted value into a CSV file using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer)
4. Use [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md) to read the random token from the CSV file created in the previous step